# DirectX 12 Questions about the command queue and command list?

Tags: c++, directx

I have been wondering this question for a while. Would this command

```
ThrowIfFailed(m_command_list->Reset(m_command_allocator.Get(), nullptr));
m_command_list->ResourceBarrier(1, &CD3DX12_RESOURCE_BARRIER::Transition(m_depth_stencil.Get(), D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_COMMON, D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_DEPTH_WRITE));
ThrowIfFailed(m_command_list->Close());
```

get sent to the command queue and not be executed?

Also how would I set the command list back into a recording state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here nothing gets sent to any queue at all.

To have a command buffer executed you would do

```
ThrowIfFailed(queue->ExecuteCommandLists(1, &m_command_list));
```

setting the command list back in the recording state is simple, just `Reset` it.